# UTF-8 Without BOM?

Tags: utf-8, dreamweaver

I use Dreamweaver and i want to save my file as UTF-8 Without BOM?

How i can do this?

Answer (score 11):

You can do this by opening the page properties and encoding. Instructions below are for Dreamweaver CS3 and are hopefully similar to the version you're using.

1. Open your document
2. Open the Modify menu
3. Choose Page Properties
4. Select the Title/Encoding submenu
5. Select the Encoding dropdown and choose Unicode (UTF-8)
6. Make sure the checkbox "Include Unicode Signature (BOM)" is unchecked.

Comment: Jordan is right but to do so permanently check your Preferences:

"Edit > Preferences > New Document"
1. Default encoding: Unicode (UTF-8)
2. Uncheck the 'Include Unicode Signature (BOM)'