# Strange letters showing up?

Tags: php, byte-order-mark

Well I had a problem with include() with blank area. Someone said open it with notepad++ and save as UTF-8 without BOM. Now I can see strange letters at blank area. How can I remove that?
And is there a way to create php without BOM in dreamweaver CC?

Comment: what is "blank area"?

Comment: [Don't use dreamweaver](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=8223283#8223283) to begin with. Also "strange letters" is not very descriptive, care to add a screen shot. Have you tried debugging with a hex editor ?

Comment: http://puu.sh/40mvI and I should because I'm using everything on it.

Comment: I mean a screenshot of the code in dreamweaver to show us those strange letters. Anyways, a hex editor may come handy, there is [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) which is pretty good for a free one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove ï»¿ from the beginning of a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-i-from-the-beginning-of-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

I assume from the question you are using windows ?

http://www.bryntyounce.com/filebomdetector.htm

Is the best BOM remover for windows I have used.

edit:

for mac open up a terminal window and

```
sed -i .bak '1 s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//' *.php
```

to stop it happening again

[UTF-8 Without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378522/utf-8-without-bom)

Comment: I'm on mac do you know any for mac? :(