# php include html adds white spaces

Tags: php, html, whitespace

I'm having troubles with multiple html pages include.
I had main index.html but it started to be a bit too complex so I decided to split it in multiple html files and each one of them inport into single index.php using php.

**index.php file**

```
<?php
include('head.html');
include('header.html');
include('slideshow.html');
include('pictureGalery.html');
include('footer.html');
include('closer.html');
?>
```

using Google Chrome Developer Tool I found, that php includes included also some white spaces (you can see them in picture in between of divs header, content, container etc... 
With a bit of googling I found some arciles about this problem, like:

- [PHP include causes white space at the top of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199355/php-include-causes-white-space-at-the-top-of-the-page) (I can't use edit cmd command because I have win7 64-bit and it is not implemented there. You can only use "open notepad " command, but these whitespaces are not visible in notepad.
- [UTF-8 Without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378522/utf-8-without-bom)
- [PHP include() before doctype, causing a white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131265/php-include-before-doctype-causing-a-white-space)

I also tried to import reset.css file (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) but it didnt work either. The **only** way that seems to **work** for me is one that posted cebasso (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14362246/1784053). But I find this way a bit too agresive and unefective.

Any other ideas how to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: `but these whitespaces are not visible in notepad.` -- Notepad isn't the only text editor. Try a different one, perhaps? Try Notepad++.

Comment: Also make sure your included files don't have trailing empty lines, php include will add them to the original doc

Comment: +1 for Notepad++ my favorite text editor.

Comment: @AmalMurali Notepad++, VisualStudio 2010, Dreamweaver, Eclipse.. all the same. I dont see these 3 BOM characters

Comment: @jayadev There are no empty lines in before or after the code

Comment: You can try  **print_r(array_map('dechex', array_map('ord', str_split(file_get_contents("xxxxxxxx.html")))));** to see if there are any problems on the file itself first :) replace the xxxxxx.html first

Comment: Removing the closing php tags `?>` from you php files could help.

Comment: @michaelMitch using your posted code I found, that first 3 characters are BOM characters> ï»û

Comment: Hi, kajiyama, then they are there, you can save your file without BOM using notepad++, or just BRUTALLY remove them as you see fit using any methods.

Comment: If you want to remove it by PHP, use the code in the answer i posted here, pasting it in comment is clumpsy. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then, ends up this is caused by unexpected BOM on the file that are included:
For future reference, I just post the code used to check by PHP plainly.

```
print_r(array_map('dechex', array_map('ord', str_split(file_get_contents("xxxxxxxxxxxxx.html")))));
```

I would definitely prefer using **Notepad++** or other software to save a **non-BOM** version,
but if still prefer using PHP to remove them, just use:
**This removes first 3 characters in the file PERMANENTLY every time you execute it, so run once only.**

```
$filename="xxxxxxx.html";
$filec = file_get_contents($filename);
file_put_contents($filename,substr($filec, 3, strlen($filec)));
```

Hopes it helps :D
Good luck!

Comment: As I have said in my question, at the moment I am using technique like you posted and works for me. I was just trying to find something clearer. Anyway thanks for help :) this will have to suffice.

Comment: No, if you look closer, it is replacing the file by overwrite with **a no BOM version**. Please see the file_put_contents

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem before a moment. but when I see BOM characters, I think of a solution. Am not sure, but these characters for `utf-8` encoding. I save my included file as `ansi` and the problems solved. also it's works fine with `encode in utf-8 without BOM` in Notepad++
**Thanx**

**Regards**

Answer (score -1):

I'd look closely at your included files. Ensure that there is no white space at the top or bottom of every one of those documents. White space is not ignored by php and will definitely be included.